# How do we actually implement the entity boundary control pattern in java?

Tags: java, swing, uml

I am trying to create a library management system. Now, I know that the boundary cannot interact with the entity directly. The control class acts as a mediator between the boundary and the entity classes. However, when are the objects of these classes created?

First, lets talk about the login. The boundary will be the login form's UI created using Java Swing. The Controller class will be PersonController which contains a function called "validateUser()". The Entity class called User contains the use's information and accesses the database.

Now, I need to create the UI, fetch username & password from the UI using action listeners and then, create a User entity with the username & password, and then, call validateUser() method of the PersonController to check if the login is correct and the user is valid.

How do I do this? Where do I create these objects?

Here's my code till now:

```
public class MainClass { // main class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonController loginSession = new PersonController(); //UNSURE
    }
}

public class PersonController {

    public PersonController(){
        LoginUI loginForm = new LoginUI(); //UNSURE
        loginForm.setVisible(true); //UNSURE
    }
    //implementation of the validateUser() function
}

public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    // get & set methods and accessing the database

}
public class LoginUI{
    //entire code for the UI in Java Swing created using Netbeans IDE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my mind the process should work something like this...

You have three elements, the UI, the model and the controller.

The UI presents choices to the user...

The model will be required to create a `User` object (as your UI should not have the knowledge of how this is actually achieved).

The controller will be responsible for responding to events from the UI and making decisions on what it should do.

When the user types in there values and clicks the "accept" action (what ever it might be), the controller captures that event and requests from the UI a `User` object.  The UI takes the information entered by the user and asks the model to create a `User` object with these values.

The controller can they validate the `User` object.

At any point any part of the process may choose to throw an exception.  As the UI is the only part of the system that can actually talk back to the user, it's the UI's responsibility to show these errors.

The basic work flow might look something like this...

Create the model, form and controller.

Add the model to the form, add the form to the controller.

The interaction between these distinct elements MUST be done via interfaces where ever possible.  No part should know more about the other part then it absolutely needs to - IMHO.

My first step would be - get it clear in your mind what it is you want to achieve.  Work out who is responsible for what and design the bridges you need to connect them together

Comment: Any feedback on the reason for the down vote would be nice, how else are we to learn and improve these answers. Otherwise you're just saying you have a personal issue with the answer, but don't have the means to quantify it